# Is it safe to reuse my seed to create a different wallet that supports Bitcoin?

Tags: wallet, mnemonic-seed

I created a wallet for Ether using MyEtherWallet. I want to store Bitcoin now, but MyEtherWallet does not support it.

Since I prefer not having two remember two different seed-phrases, I was thinking of just reusing the 12 word seed-phrase of MyEtherWallet to create a new wallet on one that does support Bitcoin, for example Electrum (I know that Electrum doesn't use the standard BI39 protocol).

I can't think of any problem with doing this, but I'm kind of new to this, so maybe there's something I haven't thought of.

Is there something I'm missing here? Is doing this considered unsafe?

EDIT: I must add that for the time being and for the foreseable future, I do not plan to spend any crypto, only accumulate. My seed-phrase was generated on an old laptop that will never be connected to the internet. The only thing that ever sees the light of day is my public address, which I use to send crypto to my wallet.

Answer (score 1):

That would be a bad idea for multiple reasons:

- It increase the risk of exposing your seed phrase since you gonna have to use it more
- It limit recovery option, if you lost your seed phrase, you will loose access to both wallet
- if one of your wallet software has a security vulnerability, you will lost fund on both chain

Comment: Please see the edit.